# Deform a 2D shape from the shapes of the 3D object

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I have a 2D shape and a 3D object.

I would like to be able to deform the 2D shape from the shapes of my 3D object.

How could I do that?

[image: Capture 2D]

Here is my 2D file

[image]

Here is my 3D file

I want to restructure the curves of my 3D shape on my 2D shape.
Basically deform my 2D from the 3D shapes

Comment: its absolutely unclear what you want to achieve ... do you have sample input/output ... images? What form you got the input vector/raster ?   deform how?  Image would be best so we can see what kind of deformation you want ... what properties ? for example area will stay the same or not ... you just want to wrap your 2D shape around 3D? fully or partialy? or there will be some form of elastics liner/nonlinear ? there are too many possibilities ...

Comment: Thanks for your return.
I have update my initial post

Comment: so your 3D is a triangulated surface in vector form. What is the 2D just raster image or also vector? what is the goal ? texture the 3D surface with 2D shape image perhaps? or projection or what ? You still did not clarify enough ...